# How to load data in sqflite database?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

```
Database database = await openDatabase(
    dbPathWithDatabase,
    version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database database, int version) async {
    print("\n\nCalling database on create\n\n");

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "database.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    print(bytes);
    await new File(dbPathWithDatabase).writeAsBytes(bytes);
  },
);
```

The above code is not copying the data to my database. But the database is created successfully.

database.db already exist in assets folder and i want to copy all the data from it.
Here i am calling it from `openDatabase` which cause the problem.

I can move the code above `openDatabase`. But i want to know the correct way to populate the data

Comment: the correct way is, to copy it before you open the Database
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already saw that doc and did that in that way. Forgot to mention it here.